# jqPlot - time values on Y axis

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I need to create graph with dates on X axis and times on Y axis.

My JS code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   var data = [["2013-04-25","00:11.557"],["2013-04-25","00:15.569"],["2013-04-25","00:11.733"],["2013-04-25","00:13.023"],["2014-04-26","00:22.333"]];
   var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [data], {
     title:'Default Date Axis',
     axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}},
     series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
     });
 });
```

The dates are showing correctly on the X axis, but I don't know how to display the values on Y axis.

How is this done in jqPlot plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the issue here.

The main issue here is `y-axis` take only `numeric` values like `11.557`, `15.569`, ... and so on.

Also, I need to add extra attribute `tickOptions` for `x-axis` as:

```
tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%m-%d'}
```

Here is what I got to work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  var data = [["2013-04-25",11.557],["2013-04-25",15.569],["2013-04-25",11.733],["2013-04-25",13.023],["2013-04-26",22.333]];
  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [data], {
    title: 'Default Date Axis',
    axes:{
      xaxis: { 
        renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
        tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%m-%d'}       
      }
    },
    series: [{ lineWidth: 4, markerOptions: { style:'square' }}]
  });
});
```

**[Working DEMO Link](http://jsbin.com/rosof/2)**

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the time value can be 05:15.569, which is difficult to translate to number only value...