# Primefaces LineChartModel: put date in Y axis

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, jqplot

I'm using JSF2 and PrimeFaces 5.1.

My problem is that I don't know how to put dates in the Y axis of my graph. It only accepts Number types.

```
/**
 * Graph's definition
 * @return LineChartModel
 * @throws ParseException
 */
public LineChartModel createLineModels() throws ParseException {
    LineChartModel lineChartModel = new LineChartModel();
    lineChartModel = initCategoryModel();
    lineChartModel.setTitle("Graph's title");
    lineChartModel.setLegendPosition("nw");
    lineChartModel.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, new CategoryAxis("PV"));

    Axis yAxis = this.lineChartModel.getAxis(AxisType.Y);
    yAxis.setTickInterval("1");
    yAxis.setLabel("Provisional dates");
    return lineChartModel;
}

/**
 * Initialization of the graph
 * @return LineChartModel
 * @throws ParseException
 */
public LineChartModel initCategoryModel() throws ParseException {

    LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();

    ChartSeries provisionalDates= new ChartSeries();
    provisionalDates.setLabel("Dates");

    //Here, I set my data in the Graph
    //In x-axis the date and the y-axis a numerical value
    provisionalDates.set("2016-01-01", 5);
    provisionalDates.set("2016-01-15", 8);

    model.addSeries(provisionalDates);

    return model;
}
```

My issue are those lines:

```
provisionalDates.set("2016-01-01", 5);
provisionalDates.set("2016-01-15", 8);
```

The method set only accept a Numerical value. I want to have date instead.

Do you know a way so I can put my dates in the Y axis?

Thanks

Comment: Does it work with a barchart?

Comment: @Kukeltje I can't use a barchart :/ I need to show my data with a linechart

Comment: Sorry, should have added 'or in the latest PF version or in plain jqplot'. Reason I asked is to narrow down the real cause

Comment: @Kukeltje The code is working. My graph is shown when I put numerical values instead of dates. My issue is that I don't know how PF deal with dates

Comment: I repeat my last comment. TRY with a newer version. See if plain jqplot can work with dates. Narrow down the possible  problem/cause

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, I misunderstood you. I'll try that :)

Comment: Might sound weird, but using dates on a y-axis might be more of a general uncommon issue. Would be weird looking graphs... And please create a [mcve] with static values...

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311003/jqplot-time-values-on-y-axis and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648685/jqplot-plot-date-on-xaxis-and-time-on-yaxis. I searched in general for 'date y-axis jqplot'. Pick the one that most closely helps you. Then I'll mark your question as a duplicate (or maybe you can create a good answer more that more specifically incorporates PrimeFaces (although it is not a PrimeFaces issue)

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your help, I finally found a solution. You were right, it wasn't a PF issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found an answer with jqPlot.

The method set only accept a numerical value so what I did is to convert my date in milliseconds.

```
long dateMS= myDate.getTime();
provisionalDates.set("2016-01-15", dateMS);
```

Then, you can add an extender to your chart with PF. The extender allows you to configure your chart:

```
model.setExtender("extender"); //Works with PF 5+
```

After that, you just need to make the extender function:

```
function extender() {
    this.cfg.axes.yaxis.tickOptions = {
        formatter: function (format, value) {
            return $.jqplot.sprintf(convertDate(value));
        }
    };
}
```

The convertDate function only convert a getTime to dd/mm/yyyy.

```
function convertDate(ms) {
    var dateReadable = new Date(ms);
    var year = dateReadable.getFullYear();
    var month = dateReadable.getMonth() + 1;
    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var day = dateReadable.getDate();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
    return day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
}
```